# Create executable of a python application

Tags: python, executable, setuptools, pyinstaller

I want to create an executable of a python application which can work on ubuntu machine.

Python setuptools has options for windows(bdist_wininst) and rmp(bdist_rpm), but i couldn't found any option in python setuptools for ubuntu or debian.

There is one more option "bdist_dumb" but i don't its use.

Questions:

1. How to create ubuntu executable using python setuptools ?
2. How pyinstaller is different from setuptools and which should i use ?

Answer (score 0):

[stdeb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stdeb) might be what you're looking for and it also works with distutils, which is similar to setuptools. Here's a simple example taken from [their repo](https://github.com/astraw/stdeb/blob/master/test_data/simple_pkg/setup.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from distutils.core import setup
import sys
setup(name='simple_pkg',
      packages=['simple_pkg'],
      version='0.1',
      author='Mister Unicodé',
      author_email='mister.unicode@example.tld',
      description='Python package with Unicodé fields',
      long_description='This is a Python package with Unicodé data.',
)
```

Comment: Is setuptools have stdeb ?

Comment: @Patrick I've been reading their info and yes, they do also support setuptools.